# Corenlp server shows different NER result from local 3.8 version

Tags: stanford-nlp

I uses the sentense

> He died in the day before yesterday.

to process corenlp NER.
On the server, I got the result like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vdtw.png).
And in local, I uses the same sentence, got the result of

He(O) died(O) in(O) the(O) day(TIME) before(O) yesterday(O) .(O)

So, how can I get the same result like the server?

Comment: Which server are you using? Is this corenlp.run or http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/ner/process ?  Also, what result do you get if you start the server locally? That should debug if it's a difference in properties being passed to the server vs locally, or if it's a code version difference between corenlp.run and your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

In order to increase the likelihood of getting a relevant answer, you may want to rephrase your question and provide a bit more information. And as a bonus, in the process of doing so, you may even find out the answer yourself ;)

For example, what url are you using to get your server result? When I check here: http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/ner/process , I can select multiple models for English. Not sure which version their API is based on (would say the most recent stable version, but I don't know). Then the title of your post suggests you are using 3.8 locally, but it wouldn't hurt to specify the relevant piece in your pom.xml file, or the models you downloaded yourself. 
What model are you using in your code? How are you calling it? (i.e. any other annotators in your pipeline that could be relevant for NER output)
Are you even calling it from code (if so, Java? Python?), or using it from the command line?

A lot of this is summarised in https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and it's not that long to read through ;)